# En C# cómo puede hacerse a un objeto invocable?

Tags: c#

Sabemos que C# tiene los llamados delegados y las funciones lambda que se tratan como objetos, pero, tiene C# el recurso de definir una clase y hacerla invocable? La duda me surge porque Python te permite lograr este efecto definiendo **call** en la clase

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo de Ptyhon, para poder ver exactamente lo que deseas

Comment: A qué te refieres con "hacerla invocable"? si te refieres a que puedas invocar código de una clase sin instanciar un objeto tienes los métodos estáticos. Si te refieres a que puedas "invocar" un objecto de un tipo de clase, puedes hacer una clase para que sea "awaitable", y escribir "x = await objecto".

Comment: No se si entendí bien lo poco que leí pero por lo que veo puedes obtener los mismos resultados en c# con métodos normales, puedes modificar el estado de la clase.